# jackson unmarshalling problems

Tags: java, json, jackson, rest-assured

I am trying to deserialize a JSON String using Jackson 2 with RestAssured (java tool for IT tests).

I have a problem. The String I am trying to deserialize is :

```
{"Medium":{"uuid":"2","estimatedWaitTime":0,"status":"OPEN_AVAILABLE","name":"Chat","type":"CHAT"}}
```

There is the object type "Medium" at the begining of the String. This cause Jackson failing during deserialization:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Medium"
```

I've set the "IGNORE_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES" to false and then I got no exception during deserialisation. However, all of my properties are 'null' in java.

```
Response getAvailability -> {"Medium":{"uuid":"2","estimatedWaitTime":0,"status":"OPEN_AVAILABLE","name":"Chat","type":"CHAT"}}
@@@ MEDIUM name -> null
@@@ MEDIUM uuid -> null
@@@ MEDIUM wait time -> null
@@@ MEDIUM wait time -> null
@@@ MEDIUM status -> null
```

Does anyone can help me ? (note: I can't change my input JSON string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put annotation 
@JsonRootName("Medium")
on your bean class and configure object mapper to 
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE).

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    "Medium": {
        "uuid": "2",
        "estimatedWaitTime": 0,
        "status": "OPEN_AVAILABLE",
        "name": "Chat",
        "type": "CHAT"
    }
}
```

as you can see uuid and other params are part of medium object , so class in which it can be deserialized is.

```
class Medium
{ 
   string name;
   // specify other params also.
}

class BaseObject
{ 
  Medium Medium;
}
```

and then use `jackson.deserialize('json', BaseObject.class)`

above i had given pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to remove the Object name that is the part of the input JSON. Since you cannot change the input string, Use this code to change this input string to a tree and get the value of "Medium" node.

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = m.readTree("{\"Medium\":{\"uuid\":\"2\",\"estimatedWaitTime\":0,\"status\":\"OPEN_AVAILABLE\",\"name\":\"Chat\",\"type\":\"CHAT\"}}");
JsonNode obj = root.get("Medium");
Medium medium = m.readValue(obj.asText, Medium.class);
```